# Detecting mouse position in viewport (not in document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a page that scrolls horizontally when user moves his mouse near left/right edge of the screen. My current code is:

```
    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousePosition = e.pageX,
            bodyWidth = config.windowWidth - 300;

        if(mousePosition >= bodyWidth) {
            $('body, html').animate({
                scrollLeft: '+=50'
            }, 100, function() {
                console.log($('body, html').scrollLeft())
            });
        }

        if(mousePosition < bodyWidth) {
            $('body, html').stop()
        }
    });
```

It works great, but only until you get a little farther. Then it gets `mousePosition` from documents point of view, not viewport's. How can I fix this?

Comment: It should be event.clientX and event.clientY if i remember well.

Comment: @Virus721 great! Please post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.clientX/Y` -> viewport

`event.pageX/Y` -> document